# Reverse Holder continuity

Tags: inequality, uniform-continuity, holder-spaces

Consider a function $f(x)$ with a point-wise Holder exponent $\beta \leq 1$.

Definition of **point-wise Holder exponent**:
$$
 \beta_x: = \sup \left\lbrace \beta: \limsup_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \left|\frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h^{\beta} } \right| =0  \right\rbrace 
$$

That is $|f(x+h) -f(x) | \leq C h^{\beta_x}$ uniformly in $[x, \delta]$,   $\delta>x$.

Is the reverse Holder inequality true:
  that is  $$ K h^{\beta_x} \leq |f(x+h) -f(x) | $$ for some $K>0$?

Remark:

Constant functions $f(x)=C $ are of any order $\beta> 1$ so they are not admissible.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, let me answer the question now that you've edited it: Let $f=0$. Clearly $f$ is $\beta$-Holder. However for any $h$, $|f(x+h)-f(x)|=0$ so there can be no such positive $K$.

Comment: I don't agree with the answer.  Take $\sqrt x$ for $x=0$.

Comment: Sure you can find an example of an $f$ which satisfies your reverse holder condition. But the example $f=0$ shows that it need not hold for *any* $f\in C^\beta$ as you asked. In fact there's no usual function space that satisfies this condition since it would have to contain $0$.

Comment: your argument is simply wrong as per my example.

Comment: @user48672 I think you are interpreting the example wrong. This is not "take any function with a zero", it is "take the zero function". The zero function is in essentially any reasonable function space, but it fails your reverse Holder inequality. Of course this is trivial, but now if you have any functions which are locally flat in one region and not locally flat somewhere else, then they fail too. That amounts to a rather severe restriction on the functions you're talking about.

Comment: The poinwise $\beta$-Holder functions are already  severely restricted. I agree with your comment if you take global Holder. But $\sqrt{x}$ is Holder $1/2$ at x=0 and Lipshitz for $x>0$. So it changes function spaces.

Comment: It's a marked restriction but it is one that generates a Banach space in a natural way. Yours does not. This creates the difficulties that have been mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps the intended question was really "characterize the functions which satisfy a holder type inequality in both directions."